# ASP.NET mvc4 - determine which attributes of model were edited

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, edit

In my app I want to log every change of certain property of model to database. So let's say I have this model:

```
public class  MyModel
{
    public int x1 {get; set;}
    public int x2 {get; set;}
}
```

And over this model I have edit action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And in this edit action I want to determine if the property x1 was changed and if so I will create log in another table, but I do not know, how to determine, which property was changed. Can anybody please give me a piece of advice how to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Side note: "Attributes" in C# means something completely different (unlike Ruby for example). I think you talking about properties.

Comment: Well yes I was refering to attributes of model as table in database so I used this word but yes of course as you pointed out I meant properties

Comment: So I rather edited it as you said

Comment: @mark_ello I see you're using EntityFramework. EF uses change tracking - leverage it to see which properties were 'dirty' at the time of save. There's more than one tutorial on the internet how to make an audit trail with EF by overriding `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing to do this in MVC. ASP.NET WebForms does this by including the original values of fields in the view state, but in embracing the statelessness of HTTP at its core MVC doesn't do this.

Comment: So @Mick Walker please how can I achieve my goal in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

So I did it with an extra hit to database Like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MyModel m = db.MyModels.Find(model.MyModelId);
            if (m.x1 != model.x1)
                //Fire log function here

            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

But if there is any better solution I would be glad to hear it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following in a partial DBContext class:

```
public bool HasChanges(MyEntity myentity)
{
  return this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.Entity == myentity &&
    (this.Entry(myentity).GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<DateTimeOffset>("aDateField") != myentity.aDateField)
  );
}
```

This will return a true if the specific field has changed. You may be able to extend this to use anonymous types but I'm not sure how to perform this.

If you want to check if entities have been changed then you could combine the following code with the above code to give you something similar.

```
public bool HasChanges()
{
  return this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added
                                          || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                                          || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
}
```

There may be a better way to do this but it will work for specific entities.